# how to check the string length in xsl and if not upto the target length means need to replaces as space

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

hii every body

```
<Table>
    <COSTUMER_NAME>praveen</COSTUMER_NAME>
</Table>
```

praveen (string length) = 7

we dont know the string length of **COSTUMER_NAME** some times it may be **less than 35**
or it was be exactly **35**

if the string length was less than be 35 then we need replace as space other than remaining string length part

Output: if i hv recieved string as **praveen**

string length was "**7**"

**so then remaining 28 character should be replaced as space**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="CUSTOMER_NAME">thestring</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of 
         select="substring(
                    concat(
                       $CUSTOMER_NAME,
                       '                                   '
                    ),
                    1,
                    35
                 )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

There are 35 white space characters there as the argument to the concat function.  So it concatenates your string and 35 space characters, then takes a substring from it of the first 35 characters, so extra whitespace is lost

Comment: Beware that also the end of the `CUSTOMER_NAME` is also lost, if the name is longer than 38 characters.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my asnswer for a short, easy and most general and reusable XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  '<xsl:sequence select=
   "my:pad(/*/*, 35, ' ')"/>'
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:pad" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pString" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="pLength" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPadChar" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "concat($pString,
           string-join(
                   for $i in 1 to $pLength - string-length($pString)
                    return $pPadChar
                    ,
                    ''
                    )
           )
   "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Table>
    <COSTUMER_NAME>praveen</COSTUMER_NAME>
</Table>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
  'praveen                            '
```

**Do note**:

1. **`<xsl:function>` is used** and this ensures complete reusability.
2. **Complete parameterization** gives us the most general, most applicable and most reusable solution.
3. **Such function can be defined almost exactly in the same way** in XQuery or as a function item in pure XPath 3.0.